# How to give accordion in ng-repeat in angular js according to click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In this code when I am clicking on span `ng-click="click_subcat(opp.ct_nm);` it is loading the content in `<span ng-click="click_pdms(opp.sbct_nm);" style="color:white;cursor:pointer">{{opp.sbct_nm}}</span>`.But problem is that when I am clicking i=on that span all are loading in `<span ng-click="click_pdms(opp.sbct_nm);" style="color:white;cursor:pointer">{{opp.sbct_nm}}</span>`

Here I the code 
(Before Click).[image]
(After Click) In Every category it is loading the same.And I want in electronics it will load laptop and mobile not in fashion.[image]

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" >
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                <!--<a ng-click="click_subcat(opp.ct_nm);">{{opp.ct_nm}}</a>-->
                <a ng-repeat="opp in res">
                    <span ng-click="click_subcat(opp.ct_nm);" style="color:white;cursor:pointer;font-size:60px;" class="accordion">
                        {{opp.ct_nm}}

                        <ul ng-repeat="opp in inp">
                            <li>
                                <span ng-click="click_pdms(opp.sbct_nm);" style="color:white;cursor:pointer">{{opp.sbct_nm}}</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added another  $scope.hiddenDiv = [] so that it will show the div according to the index of that main $scope index.

```
$scope.click_subcat = function (btnval,index)
    {
        var responsed;
        $scope.hiddenDiv = [];
        var urlg = 'http://localhost/Publish/ProductSubCategory/GET?sbct=' + btnval;
        $http.get(urlg).then(function (responsed)
        {

            $scope.hiddenDiv[index] = !$scope.hiddenDiv[index];
            $scope.inp = responsed.data;
        });
    };
```

and Added another div to make it visible true and false.